# php file with HTML mail does not send image files

Tags: php, html, email

I want to send an email to the user folowed in my php function with the body of the email in HTML. Like this...

```
<?php
//new function


require_once '../PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';

$to = "myself@myself.com.br";
$nameto = "Alessandro Nardinelli";
$from = "adm@adm.com.br";
$namefrom = "AAA";
$subject = "BBB";
$corpo = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" />
<title>Email de SMS</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#8d8e90">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#8d8e90">
  <tr>
    <td><table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
              <tr>
                <td width="100"><img src="images/EmailSMS/logo_sms.png" width="85" height="85" border="0" alt=""/></a></td>
                <td width="100"><img src="images/EmailSMS/alerta_text.png" width="110" height="15" border="0" alt=""/></a></td>
                <td width="393"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
```

Notice that there are two images on my mail html code...

```
<td width="100"><img src="images/EmailSMS/logo_sms.png" width="85" height="85" border="0" alt=""/></a></td>
<td width="100"><img src="images/EmailSMS/alerta_text.png" width="110" height="15" border="0" alt=""/></a></td>
```

Now, both of the images are not following up with the email, but, if i run the html itself, the images have no problem beeing assigned, so their path are correct.

My php send mail function is

```
function smtpmailer($para, $de, $de_nome, $assunto, $corpo) { 
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();        // Ativar SMTP
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;       // Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // Autenticação ativada
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';    // SSL REQUERIDO pelo GMail
    $mail->Host = 'webmail.host.com.br';    // SMTP utilizado
    //$mail->Port = 587;        // A porta 587 deverá estar aberta em seu servidor
    $mail->Username = GUSER;
    $mail->Password = GPWD;
    $mail->SetFrom($de, $de_nome);
    $mail->Subject = $assunto;
    $mail->Body = $corpo;
    $mail->AddAddress($para);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        echo $error;
                return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Mensagem enviada!';
                echo $error;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Why does the images not beeing send over email but are showing correct in the html code? how can i solve this?

Thanks!!

Comment: It is best to upload your images and then email them with a `src="http://domain.com/img.jpg"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images need to be referenced at their full path. For example: http://yourwebsite.com/yourimage.jpg